# UIImageView load image from URL using VIPER

Tags: ios, swift, viper-architecture

I have a VIPER home module which shows a UITableView. Each cell has a UIImageView which loads a image from the internet.

I would not like to perform a network call in my UIViewController(View), so I was thinking about defining the method which downloads an image, in a Service class. Would be recommended to make all the componentes call chain to ask for an image(View->Presenter->Interactor->InputRemoteData->Service)? if not, what is the best approach?

About the UITableView, would you recommend to set dataSource methods out of the view (UIViewController)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be very strict about it your Interactor would have to fetch your image data and your Presenter would convert it to a UIImage (as it is UI related). In practice, however, a library like SDWebImage, which has an extension for UIImageView and which fetches the image for you, is perfectly fine to be used directly in your view controller.